# mod_jk not able to connect Apache and tomcat

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, apache2, mod-jk

I am not able to connect my Apache to tomcat servers. Below are the version details.
mod_jk/1.2.39
Apache-2.4.41
tomcat-9.0.31

I have created Workers.properties file and mentioned my hostname and AJP port i.e. 8009 and also enabled Ajp connectors from tomcat side. Issue I am facing is mod_jk is not connecting to host that I have provided in workers.properties file. Instead of that it is connecting to 0.0.0.0. Below is the error from mod_jk.log

```
[Wed May 27 12:52:00 2020] [6902:140379841652544] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3383): mod_jk/1.2.39 initialized
[Wed May 27 12:52:00 2020] [6903:140379841652544] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3383): mod_jk/1.2.39 initialized
[Wed May 27 12:53:20 2020] [6906:140379663890176] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (735): connect to 0.0.0.0:8009 failed (errno=111)
[Wed May 27 12:53:20 2020] [6906:140379663890176] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1019): Failed opening socket to (0.0.0.0:8009) (errno=111)
[Wed May 27 12:53:20 2020] [6906:140379663890176] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1659): (tomcat1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
```

I have checked I can access my tomcat servers and it's running fine. Below is the Ajp connectors from tomcat server

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Is there anything I am missing or is it some kind of fat bug involve with this version of mod_jk?
Any kind of Suggestion and Help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Anshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start tomcat server on IP address instead of 0.0.0.0.

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="IP-address"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Use tomcat-adress and Port in worker.properties. Restart tomcat and Apache service. Also make sure that port 8009 is open between Apache and tomcat server.

Comment: Thanks for reply, By tomcat-address you mean <IP-address> instead of host name that I have mentioned in workers.properties

Comment: You are using address="::1" in server.xml.Use tomcat machine IP address in server.xml file. Also, use the same IP in the worker.properties file

Comment: Yes, That worked. Seems like Apache tomcat 9 got that extra parameter i.e. <address>. I  never saw this field in AJP connector Apache 7. BTW once again Thanks